# Problems regarding the prefix of TOC lists while hiding appendix caption/section titles in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

Please take a look at the provided minimal example. I try to achive the following three things:

1. Add "Equation" as prefix for each entry in the list of equations
2. Add "SpecialAlgorithm" as prefix for each entry in the list of SpecialAlgorithms

Requirement 1 should be solved by setting the `names` attribut in the `\DeclareNewTOC[..]{equ}` statement, but this does not work.

Requirement 3 should be solved by setting the `\addtocontents{loa}{\def\string\figurename{SpecialAlgorithm}}` directly after the `\listofalgorithms` command, but each algorithm is displayed with the prefix "Fig.". I dont know why it uses the customised prefix of the figures.

Please support me, I cant figure it out on myself. I appreciate every help and suggestion. Thank you!

```
\documentclass[
  paper=a4,
  fontsize=12pt,
  twoside=false,
  open=right,
  numbers=noenddot,
  listof=nochaptergap,
  listof=totoc,% lists in toc
  %toc=sectionentrywithdots,
  ]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}  
\usepackage[final]{listings}  
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalcolor\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{0pt}} 
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace*{15pt}} 

% HEADER SEPERATION LINE
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{chngcntr}  % Counter für durchgängige Nummerierung 
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}   
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{ 
    \begingroup 
    \listof{algorithm}{SpecialAlgorithm} 
    \endgroup 
}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2cm}                     
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2cm}                                           
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0cm}                                                     
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0cm} 

\usepackage[justification=centering,labelfont=bf]{caption} 
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Fig. }
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Tab. }  

\BeforeStartingTOC[lof]{\def\autodot{:}}
\BeforeStartingTOC[lot]{\def\autodot{:}}

\DeclareNewTOC[ 
type=equation, 
name={Equationl}, 
types=equations, 
listname={List of equations}, 
forcenames
]{equ} 
\newcommand{\equationentry}[2][\theequation]{% 
    \addxcontentsline{equ}{equation}[{#1}]{#2}% 
} 
\BeforeStartingTOC[equ]{\def\autodot{:}} 

\usepackage{scrhack} 
\makeatletter
\def\l@lstlisting#1#2{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{1em}{\hspace{1,5em} Lst. #1}{#2}}
\@removefromreset{footnote}{chapter}
\newenvironment{megaalgorithm}[1][htb]{%
    \renewcommand{\ALG@name}{SpecialAlgorithm}% Update algorithm name
    \begin{algorithm}[#1]%
    }{\end{algorithm}}
\makeatother

\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0.2cm}

\begin{document}
    % CHOOSE "ngerman" or "english"
    \selectlanguage{ngerman}

    \frontmatter  % ROMAN NUMBERING
    \pagenumbering{Roman}              

    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of SpecialAlgorithms}
    \listofalgorithms
    \addtocontents{loa}{\def\string\figurename{SpecialAlgorithm}}
    \listofequations

    \mainmatter % ARABIC NUMBERING            

    \chapter{Test}
    \section{Test 1}
    \chapter{Test 2}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{5cm}|*{1}{X}}
        \caption[Table1]{Table1} \\
        \label{tab:table1}
        %\toprule
        column & column \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \toprule
        column & column \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        column & column \\
        \addlinespace
        %\bottomrule 
    \end{tabularx}

    \begin{equation}\label{eq:Eq1}
    N_{v} = N_{r}
    \equationentry{Berechnung der Anzahl der Werte einer Partition} 
    \end{equation}

    \begin{megaalgorithm}[H]\small
        \caption[Example-Algorithm]{Example-Algorithm}
        \label{algo:Worker-Thread}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \For{i in range}
            \State print(i) 
            \EndFor
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{megaalgorithm}

   \appendix
    \chapter*{Appendix}
    \phantomsection
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Anhang}
    %\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-0.5em}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\appendixname} 
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\value{tocdepth}=0}

    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

    \section{Apendix Test}
    \subsection{Apendix Test 1}

\end{document}
```

Update: Former Requirement 1: Hide the sections and chapters of the appendix was solved by using `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\value{tocdepth}=0}` directly after the \appendix command.

Comment: These are three questions. Generally it is better to ask one question per question only. And please have a look into your `log` file. There are warnings, because of using obsolete/deprecated options and packages, because of not recommended package combinations (resulting in additional warnings), unknown options, and wrong usage of `appendix`. I would suggest to solve all these problems first.

Comment: @Schweinebacke, thank you for your fast response! You are right, I asked three three questions, but I think the issue is somehow related. Especially requirement 1 and 2. Your hint to resolve the obsolete/deprecated options and packages etc. was also helpful. I resolved this and updated my minimal example. Unfortunately the result regarding my initial issue is the same.

Comment: I am interested: Who is going to read the final document?

Comment: @Johannes_B, I am a student and the document is part of my final thesis. Therefore my professor is going to read the final document. Why are you asking?

Comment: What would you expect in a *list of figures*? Personally, i would expect to have figures listed there. No socks or bananas. I find it ridiculous to have the word figure (or equation or whatever) next to every list item.

Comment: One the one hand this is correct, on the other hand, looking from this point of view it does not solve my problem at all. It would work for the list of algorithms, but the list of equations is still formatted in a different way. I try to resolve this issue, but I think removing the prefix is more a workaround than a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use package `tocloft` together with a KOMA-Script class.

```
\documentclass[
  paper=a4,
  fontsize=12pt,
  twoside=false,
  open=right,
  numbers=noenddot,
  listof=nochaptergap,
  listof=totoc,% lists in toc
  listof=entryprefix,% <- added
  captions=tableheading,% <- added
  ]{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[main=ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}% <- option removed
\usepackage[final]{listings}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalcolor\bfseries}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1sp,% <- skip before chapter titles
  afterskip=15pt,% <- skip after chapter titles
  tocbeforeskip=0.2cm% <- skip before chapter entries in TOC
]{chapter}

\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline,
  automark% <- added
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
\counterwithout*{footnote}{chapter}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}% loads also tabularx
\usepackage[justification=centering,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\providecaptionname{ngerman}{\listoflofentryname}{Abb.}
\providecaptionname{ngerman}{\listoflotentryname}{Tab.}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \doforeachtocfile[float]{\BeforeStartingTOC[#1]{\def\autodot{:}}}%
}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\addtotoclist[float]{loa}
\renewcommand\listofalgorithms{\listoftoc[{List of SpecialAlgorithms}]{loa}}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level=1,
  indent=0pt,
  numwidth=2.3em
]{tocline}{algorithm}
\providecaptionname{english}{\listofloaentryname}{SpecialAlgorithm}
\providecaptionname{ngerman}{\listofloaentryname}{SpecialAlgorithm}

\DeclareNewTOC[ 
  type=equation, 
  name={Equation}, 
  types=equations, 
  listname={List of equations}
]{equ} 
\newcommand{\equationentry}[2][\theequation]{% 
    \addxcontentsline{equ}{equation}[{#1}]{#2}% 
}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{megaalgorithm}[1][htb]{%
  \renewcommand{\ALG@name}{SpecialAlgorithm}% Update algorithm name
  \begin{algorithm}[#1]%
  }
  {\end{algorithm}}
\makeatother

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter  % ROMAN NUMBERING
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listofalgorithms
\listofequations

\mainmatter % ARABIC NUMBERING            
\blinddocument
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{5cm}|*{1}{X}}
  \caption[Table1]{Table1} \\
  \label{tab:table1}
  %\toprule
  column & column \\
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \toprule
  column & column \\
  \midrule
  \endhead
  column & column \\
  \addlinespace
  %\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Eq1}
  N_{v} = N_{r}
  \equationentry{Berechnung der Anzahl der Werte einer Partition} 
\end{equation}

\begin{megaalgorithm}[H]\small
  \caption[Example-Algorithm]{Example-Algorithm}
  \label{algo:Worker-Thread}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \For{i in range}
    \State print(i) 
    \EndFor
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{megaalgorithm}

\blinddocument

\appendix
\addchap{Appendix}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\value{tocdepth}=0}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\section{Apendix Test}
\subsection{Apendix Test 1}
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]